# Get a default customizeAction text for a section using Customizer JS API

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, api

What is the best way to get a default **customizeAction** label for 
the Customizer sections added via JavaScript?

Here is a code with a custom action label:

```
customSection = new api.Section( 'my_section', {
  priority: 1,
  panel: 'my_panel',
  title: 'Testing Section',
  customizeAction: 'Custom Action'
} );
```

The default value of **customizeAction** is an empty string.

Is it possible to display [a default text](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/685e3c1a6708924972cdd6a8b2a1801b1009b88a/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-section.php#L221) -- "Customizing" ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that `customizeAction` does not currently have a default value of `"Customizing"` and so you have to explicitly provide it for each instance?

Comment: Correct. The problem is that if `customizeAction` is not defined in a custom section then it causes a styling issue in the Customizer: https://snag.gy/UJZjNd.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. There's currently [no default value for the `customizeAction` param](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4af1237176c326e7840361fd580fdc3f97841e6a/src/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js#L1392).

You can add your own default value for all controls with something like this in PHP:

```
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'customize-controls',
        sprintf(
            'wp.customize.Section.prototype.defaults.customizeAction = %s;',
            wp_json_encode( __( 'Customizing', 'default' ) )
        )
    );
} );
```

This isn't in core yet because the default value is actually variable based on whether there is a `panel` defined. This is something we should figure out and improve in core. See [#42635](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42635).